# Animations in JavaFX using RxJava without blocking GUI

Tags: java, javafx, rx-java

This is a simple class that uses bubble sort to sort a `List` of `Integer`s and push the result of every iteration to a `Subject` from RxJava library, with some delay.

```
public class Sorter {
    private PublishSubject<List<Integer>> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    public void bubbleSort(int delay) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Integer> ints = randomIntegers(0,200,10);
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ints.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (ints.get(j) > ints.get(j + 1)) {
                    Collections.swap(ints, j, j + 1);
                    subject.onNext(ints);
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Integer> randomIntegers(int origin, int bound, int limit) {
        return new Random()
                .ints(origin, bound)
                .limit(limit)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public PublishSubject<List<Integer>> getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
}
```

I can observe the result very easily with a sample code:

```
int delay = 100;
Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
PublishSubject<List<Integer>> subject = sorter.getSubject();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
sorter.bubbleSort(delay);
```

I want, however, to see the results of the iterations as moving rectangles of different height representing the numbers. I use JavaFX. After every iteration, I want to clear the application window and redraw everything.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Group root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
        root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
        PublishSubject<List<Integer>> subject = sorter.getSubject();
        subject.subscribe(this::drawRectangles);
        sorter.bubbleSort(100);

    }

    private void drawRectangles(List<Integer> integers) {
        root.getChildren().clear();
        rectangles.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i<integers.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(i * 20, 500 - integers.get(i), 10, integers.get(i));
            rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            rectangles.add(rectangle);
        }
        root.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

However, I only see the last iteration's result. Prior to that, I can only see that the application is running and the GUI thread is blocked.

How can I make the background RxJava calculations non-blocking to my GUI?

EDIT: I solved the issue by running the computation code in another thread, like so:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {

    new Thread(() -> {
        Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
        sorter.getSubject().subscribe(this::drawRectangles);
        try {
            sorter.bubbleSort(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();


    root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1500, 500, Color.WHITE);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
}
```

And wrapper the `drawRectangles` in `Platform.runLater(() -> {}` expression.

This seems to be working, although I feel like there might me a possibility to run this with `observeOn` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RxJavaFX` scheduler your UI tasks.

You need do the sort task `sorter.bubbleSort` in another thread instead of UI thread. And

```
observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.getInstance())
```

to schedule UI task back into UI thread.

Only change your `start` method to:

```
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
    root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.WHITE);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    sorter.getSubject()
        .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
        .subscribe(this::drawRectangles);
    new Thread(() -> uncheck(() -> sorter.bubbleSort(100))).start();
  }
```

Comment: Which version of the RxJavaFX did you use? I cannot compile this code because `observeOn` is expecting an `rx.Scheduler` and `JavaFxScheduler` is an `io.reactivex.Scheduler`. Also, what is the `uncheck` method in the lambda expression used to start a new thread with computation?

Comment: @Scramjet Sorry, I didn't say clearly. You can use RxJavaFX1 if you use RxJava1 and change `JavaFxScheduler.platform()` to `JavaFxScheduler.getInstance()`. And the `uncheck` is a utility method ignore the checked exception. You can use `try...catch...` to ignore the `InterruptException`.

Comment: @Scramjet Here is the link for `RxJavaFX`. [LINK](http://www.mvnrepository.com/search?q=rxjavafx)